# How can I combine two similar while loops in C?

Tags: c, loops, control-flow

I am going through K&R C and am currently trying to make my code for Exercise 1-22 more readable. I have two loops like so

```
while (spaces != 0) {
        buf[pos]=' ';
        ++pos;
        --spaces;
}
while (tabs != 0) {
        buf[pos]='\t';
        ++pos;
        --tabs;
}
```

`spaces` and `tabs` are integers which count preceding spaces and tabs respectively and `buf[pos]` is a char array. The goal is to insert preceding spaces and tabs when a character is encountered. `spaces` is set to 0 when a tab is encountered and `tabs` is set to 0 when a space is encountered.

Is there any other way of expressing these two loops or is this the most readable form?

Comment: You can shorten it if you want: `while (--tabs != 0) buf[++pos] = '\t';`

Comment: @SeetheMoar It is unclear what you are trying to do with these loops,

Comment: I just pulled my copy of K&R from the shelf just to see what this exercise is about. It's not entirely clear what these two loops you present are supposed to do. Can you add more context to the question about what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: I have updated the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Shorter but identical, `while(spaces) buf[pos++] = ' ', spaces--;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's is quite readable.

I would go with the following:

```c
while ( spaces-- )
   buf[ pos++ ] = ' ';

while ( tabs-- )
   buf[ pos++ ] = '\t';
```

If you really wanted to eliminate the duplication, use a function.

```c
void append_n_ch( char *buf, size_t *pos, size_t count, char ch ) {
   while ( count-- ) {
      buf[ (*pos)++ ] = ch;
}

append_n_ch( buf, &pos, spaces, ' '  );
append_n_ch( buf, &pos, tabs,   '\t' );
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter if one is not using `spaces` (of `tabs`) again (which seems to be likely), but this is not quite the same in that the final value is -1 instead of 0 like in the original code.